# removing all leading occurences of [[:space:]]* and #*

Tags: bash, shell-script, sed

the input file has lines:

```
line1
##### 1592524754
   ### okoko
  ##  ### ##  sfsffsf
```

the expected output is:

```
line1
1592524754
okoko
sfsffsf
```

I can only replace one set of [[:space:]]* and #'shes at one sed

```
$ cat temp_file|sed 's/^[[:space:]]*//;s/^[[:space:]]*\#*//'
line1
 1592524754
 okoko
  ### ##  sfsffsf
$

$ cat temp_file|sed 's/^[[:space:]]*//;s/^[[:space:]]*\#*//;s/^[[:space:]]*//;s/^[[:space:]]*\#*//;s/^[[:space:]]*\#*//;s/^[[:space:]]*//'
line1
1592524754
okoko
sfsffsf
$
```

Is there an easy way to remove all with one sed filter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`^[[:blank:]#]*` will match zero or more horizontal whitespace or `#` characters, anchored to the start of the line.

So

```
$ sed 's/^[[:blank:]#]*//' temp_file
line1
1592524754
okoko
sfsffsf
```